# When i tell Visual Basic to set a label's text to 1, it sets it to 2

Tags: visual-studio-2013

You might already know the problem by the title.
I'm making a game, where i want the level number to change to 1 (from the first level 0). My code to change from level 0 to 1 is:

```
    'Level 0 (Tutorial)
    If levelNum.Text.Contains("0") Then
        levelNum.Text = "1"
        ButtonNext.Enabled = False
        ButtonLeave.Enabled = True
        ButtonBreak.Enabled = True
        ButtonCoffee.Enabled = True
        ButtonCoffeeForBoss.Enabled = True
    End If
```

But it sets the label text to 2 instead of 1, wich was written (Line 3 of code above).

**EXAMPLE:**
http://cdn.makeagif.com/media/11-24-2013/9p4CcG.gif

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Maybe make a variable with "1" in it and then use that?

*TESTING THAT*

No, didn't work...
Could it be because it's starting on level 0?
I have no idea.
I'm using VB Express 2013.

Comment: There is only one line here that modifies the label. It sets the label to a constant value of "1". Conclusion: after (or instead of) this code, another pieces of code that sets the value to "2".

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code, then step through it to see exactly what is happening. There is something else in your code that is modifying your Label, what you show here will set it to 1.